# Как сверстать круг, разделенный на цвета

Tags: html, css, svg, color

Нужен наиболее верный способ. Можно для примера разделить круг на 3 сегмента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-нибудь вроде такого: https://codepen.io/AtomicNoggin/pen/fEish ?

Comment: Делаем круглый треугольник и вращаем.

Comment: @Qwertiy "круглый треугольник" это сильно! :)

Comment: @Isaev, зато понятно. Кстати, там ответ есть с этим треугольником.

Answer (score 11):

Вот такая функция, рисующая сектора на SVG:

```js
var drSegment = function (style, ange1, ange2) {

        var dir = "0";
        if (angle2 - angle1 > 0.5 ) dir = "1";
        var angle1 = Math.PI * 2 * ange1;
        var angle2 = Math.PI * 2 * ange2;
        
        var rad=300, cx=350, cy=350;
        
        var dx1 = Math.sin(angle1) * rad + cx;
        var dy1 = -Math.cos(angle1) * rad + cy;
        
        var dx2 = Math.sin(angle2) * rad + cx;
        var dy2 = -Math.cos(angle2) * rad + cy; 
        
        var el= document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
        
        el.setAttribute('style', style);
        el.setAttribute('d', ' M '+dx1+','+dy1+' A '+rad+','+rad+' 0 ' + dir + ' 1 ' + dx2 + ',' + dy2 + ' L '+cx+','+cy+' Z');

        document.getElementById('s').appendChild(el);
        
}

drSegment('fill:red; stroke:black; stroke-width:3;', -1/6, 1/6)
drSegment('fill:yellow; stroke:black; stroke-width:3;', 1/6, 3/6)
drSegment('fill:blue; stroke:black; stroke-width:3;', 3/6, 5/6)
```

```html
<svg id='s' width="100%"  viewBox="0 0 700 700"></svg>
```

Comment: Очевидный плюс в отличие от остальных решений - обводка секторов

Answer (score 9):

Делаем круглый треугольник из подрезанного полукруга, потом вращаем эти треугольники, чтобы получился круг:

```css
section {
  width: 10em;
  height: 5em;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  margin: 1em;
  float: left;
}

.circle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: silver;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 100% 100% 0 0;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.triangle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle .circle {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.chart {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden; /* .triangle выходят за пределы */
}

.chart:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.chart .triangle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="triangle">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="chart">
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate(   0deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#000"></div></div>
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate( -60deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#F00"></div></div>
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate(-120deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#0F0"></div></div>
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate(-180deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#00F"></div></div>
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate(-180deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#00F"></div></div>
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate(-240deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#F0F"></div></div>
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate(-300deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#FF0"></div></div>
</section>
```

Ну и окончательный код:

```css
section {
  width: 12em;
  margin: auto;
}

.chart {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* .triangle выходят за пределы */
}

.chart:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: silver;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 100% 100% 0 0;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="chart">
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate(   0deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#ff7f00"></div></div>
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate( -60deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#ff0000"></div></div>
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate(-120deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#9400d3"></div></div>
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate(-180deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#4b0082"></div></div>
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate(-180deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#0000ff"></div></div>
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate(-240deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#00ff00"></div></div>
  <div class="triangle" style="transform:rotate(-300deg)"><div class="circle" style="background:#ffff00"></div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: круглый треугольник - это несколько иное

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, тот, у которого все 3 стороны круглые, в этом вопросе не нужен :)

Comment: ага, треугольник Рёло, а в ответе же сектор

Answer (score 8):

1. Делаем градиентами три одноцветных полукруга ([как предложил @nueq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676491/208926)).
2. Поворачиваем их по трём направлениям.
3. Добавляем `background-blend-mode: multiply;` (не работает [в IE и Edge](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-blend-mode)).

Получаем шесть разноцветных секторов. Трудность в том, чтобы подобрать правильные ингредиенты ;) У меня получилось без оранжевого сектора.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/PjPPjJ

```css
.colors {
  background:
    linear-gradient(    0deg, #f0f 50%, transparent 50% ),
    linear-gradient(  120deg, #ff0 50%, transparent 50% ),
    linear-gradient( -120deg, #0ff 50%, transparent 50% );
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px; height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"></div>
```

Comment: Прикольный способ, но все 6 цветов задать не удастся.

Comment: @Qwertiy, потому что обозреватели работают с цветами  через одно место. По хорошему, перед смешиванием цветов [их надо линеаризовывать гамма-коррекцией](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw). Но я сильно сомневаюсь, что хоть какой-то из обозревателей это делает.

Answer (score 1):

Если на 2 - можно градиентом:

```css
.gradient-circle{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: linear-gradient(to left, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-circle">
</div>
```

Если больше сегментов - SVG (тут рисовать самому) либо Canvas (пример библиотеки - http://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-pie-chart/)

Comment: На html тоже можно.