# Возможно сделать pie chart на чистом css

Tags: html, css

Стоит задача написать pie chart (кругавая диаграма) на чистом CSS. Есть ли возможность реализовать это?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы не дублировать ответ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205652/how-to-draw-a-circle-sector-in-css - ровно ваша задача (лучший ответ). Остаётся только надписи добавить, но с этим, думаю, проще.

Comment: На русском языке уже есть похожая заметка (но там пример менее полный, поэтому не стал его приводить) - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676477/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0/676563

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ровно то, что мне необходимо было.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть желание сделать именно на html-элементах без svg, то надо полукруглый div повернуть в контейнере с overflow hidden - получится сектор. Сам контейнер надо повернуть до желаемого положения. По необходимости можно расставить pointer-events, чтобы можно было наводить на сектора в отдельности.

Код с пояснениями имеется [в соседнем вопросе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676530/178988).

Answer (score 0):

тут есть погрешности, нет времени их исправлять, идею ты понял, дальше сам разберешься...

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #272727
}

#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: transparent;
 border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/*
*/

.round_graphics {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
 
}

.round_graphics:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: green;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 100%, 75% 100%, 50% 50%);
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.round_graphics:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: orange;
  clip-path: polygon(14% 100%, 75% 100%, 50% 50%);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.round_graphics:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 100%, 75% 100%, 50% 50%);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.round_graphics:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 100%, 75% 100%, 50% 50%);
  transform: rotate(245deg);
}

.round_graphics:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 100%, 75% 100%, 50% 50%);
  transform: rotate(145deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="round_graphics"></div>
  <div class="round_graphics"></div>
  <div class="round_graphics"></div>
  <div class="round_graphics"></div>
  <div class="round_graphics"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Идею я понял, подобный вид чартов не юзабельный совсем.

Comment: Здесь сегменты рисуются полигонами, которые в свою очередь прячутся родительский "круг" с overflow:hidden; В таком сучае, каким образом я могу например определить размер сегмента чарта на 15% например, разве что на глаз, а расчёты должны быть точными

Comment: разберись с clip-path...  и будет понятнее чем надо...  но на сколько я знаю, это наилучший вариант на css

Comment: в IE 11 не работает