# Как сделать круговой прогресс бар на javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как реализовать анимацию кругового прогресс бара на чистом javascript?
Интересен момент, как сделать заполнение окружности цветом

Comment: Здравствуйте! В вашем вопросе видно непонимание темы. Что значит реализовать на чистом javascript? когда внешний вид может задаваться с помощью стилей(css). Вам возможно нужно реализовать анимацию на js? Пока минус поставил вашему вопросу. Напишите подробнее, уберу минус. Всего доброго и хорошего вам дня!

Comment: codepen.io => поиск => radial progress bar
Выбирайте какая реализация понятней/больше нравится.
Пример https://codepen.io/nelsyeung/pen/MwdWmj

Comment: Можно на css сделать... но по своему опыту скажу что это не лучшая идея. Не дури себе голову сделай на svg + js или canvas + js. А примеры на кодпене посмотри, как тебе уже подсказали.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676530/178988 - так?

Comment: https://medium.com/@andsens/radial-progress-indicator-using-css-a917b80c43f9

Comment: Вот так, например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628297/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80

Answer (score 1):

**Добрый день.**

Если коротко, то вы создаете круг, внутри центрируете еще один круг
и со временем, круг внутри увеличиваете по ширине и высоте.

**Сделал вам пример :** 
https://codepen.io/AndreyMyP/pen/Mrqbvx

```
<!-- Обертка, чтобы центрировать -->
<div class="wrapper wrapper__align-inside">
  <!-- Внешний круг -->
  <div class="circle circle__block circle_cosmetics">
    <!-- Процент загрузки в числе -->
    <div id="jsCount" class="circle__count circle__count_cosmetics">0 %</div>
    <!-- Внутренний круг  -->
    <div id="jsSize" class="circle__item circle__item_cosmetics"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```