# Как оформить диаграмму в css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Верстаю макет и не знаю как сделать такие 3 диаграммы, точнее как правильно оформить. Сделал такую в 75%, но не знаю как сделать такую чтобы выглядела в 50 80 и 35 процентов. Можно ли это оформить на CSS или всё-таки нужно применять JS?

```css
 div {
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 40px/190px Times, serif;
    border: 2px solid #95CD8B;
    border-right: 2px solid #D0E6BB;
    border-radius: 100%;
   }
   span {
    font-size: 0.6em;
   }
```

```html
<div>75<span>%</span></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Идеи [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676530/178988) могут помочь. Ну и ещё можно svg использовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: на css можно, точно видел и даже один раз для полукруга делал, но слишком заморочено ... куда проще и поддерживаевиме - какой-нибудь jquery circle progress

Comment: @MedvedevDev, куда проще - это svg с двумя кругами. Или даже с одним. А не тащить всякую муть, которая непонятно что делает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, svg не все понимают (в том числе и я не силен), если нужны закругленные края у концов диаграммы - тоже проблемы, если круг должен не полностью заполняться, а 100% скажем равны 90% длины окружности ... просто совсем недавно такую штуку надо было сделать, я сначала думал сам реализовать, а потом пока искал, наткнулся на плагин и мне стало лень дальше самому заморачиваться, тем более, что в той части сайта jquery уже был подключен .... в общем ситуативно и дело вкуса.

Comment: @Qwertiy К сожалению я тоже не силён в svg. Я так понял при помощи css это не как не оформить

Comment: @BraFik, можно, скажем - https://codepen.io/jo-asakura/pen/stFHi, вот только не знаю, это интересно для саморазвития, но вот в реальном проекте использовать как-то не комильфо (личное мнение).

Comment: @MedvedevDev Да это жостко, думаете лучше использовать в проекте  jquery circle progress, так проще будет?

Comment: @BraFik, если вам не нужны какие-нибудь анимации и кастомизация, чисто сделать статику, то я бы взял css вариант допилив под себя. В противном случае я бы выбрал плагин.

Comment: @MedvedevDev хорошо я понял, да я не думал что создание диограммы в css это проблемма. Спасибо, буду доучиватся.

Comment: Я же показал пример с 6 секторами - делается точно так же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG + CSS Custom Properties. В общем классе диаграммы надо задать основные параметры: диаметр диаграммы и толщину линии, а в классе конкретной диаграммы — цвета, заполненность (от 0 до 1) и параметр скругления линий (`miter`, `round`, `bevel`).

```css
.diagram {
  --diameter: 300;
  --stroke-w: 10;
  
  width: calc(var(--diameter) * 1px);
  height: calc(var(--diameter) * 1px);
}

.diagram--redblack50round {
  --color: red;
  --bg: black;
  --percent: 0.5;
  --linecap: round;
}

.diagram--blueblack90miter {
  --color: blue;
  --bg: black;
  --percent: 0.9;
  --linecap: miter;
}

.diagram__circle {
  cx: calc(var(--diameter) / 2);
  cy: calc(var(--diameter) / 2);
  r: calc((var(--diameter) - var(--stroke-w)) / 2);  
  stroke: var(--color);
  stroke-linecap: var(--linecap);
  stroke-width: calc(var(--stroke-w) * 1px);
  stroke-dasharray: calc(3.14 * var(--diameter) * var(--percent));
}
```

```html
<svg class="diagram diagram--redblack50round">
  <circle class="diagram__circle"></circle>
</svg>

<svg class="diagram diagram--blueblack90miter">
  <circle class="diagram__circle"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, как вы думаете стоит ли сейчас изучать svg, насколько он часто встречается в проектах, и на сколько он актуален?

Comment: Стоит изучить хотя бы основы, чтобы понимать что это такое и как это работает. В современном вебе много векторной графики, взять те же иконки, например, которые не должны быть замыленными на экранах любой плотности пикселей — именно для этого SVG и используется.