# Как построить дугу из div-блоков?

Tags: html, css

подскажите, как можно реализовать дугу из дивов(эти части будут выводиться из бд)

Comment: точно из div-ов?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ желательно, но рассмотрю и другие варианты

Comment: так то они только прямоугольные могут быть

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это не важно, их нужно расположить дугой

Comment: Вложить их друг в друга, а потом все пачкой закрыть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это легко сделать по формуле:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
  document.body.innerHTML += `<div style="
      transform: rotate(${i*20-100}deg);
      top: ${110+Math.sin(i/Math.PI-Math.PI)*100}px;
      left: ${300+Math.cos(i/Math.PI-Math.PI)*100}px"
  >${i}</div>`
```

```css
div{
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, попробую ваш вариант.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982787/188366

Comment: сколько я не пытался, гуглил, но так и не смог понять, как это интегрировать в уже готовый for. Пример того, чего я хочу сделать http://playroll.ru/

Comment: Вы про with (Math) ?, ща подправлю

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/973077/188366

Comment: я про то, как это вставить в php код? а именно for, у меня выводиться только 1 раз(

Comment: странно, должно работать, предлагаю Вам создать еще один вопрос уже про php