# SVG Circle | Линейный градиент для круга с динамическим заполнением

Tags: svg, градиент

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="0" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ec0143" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ff6d6d" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="9" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="none" stroke-width="9" stroke-dasharray="282.2865905761719" stroke-dashoffset="200" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="url(#gradient)" />
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Имеются два круга, один задается как фон, второй задается как показатель заполненности, проблема в том, что при использовании градиента, он независимо от `stroke-dashoffset` заполняет градиент на весь объем фигуры, а не на ту часть, которая нужна.

То есть нужен градиент на ту часть, которая отрисована, кусочек круга если быть точнее.

Второй вектор показывает, что градиент заполняет полностью объем и создан как пример.

Как добиться заполнение объема фигуры градиентом только на определенном кусочке который задается с помощью `strok-dashoffset` ?

Comment: я не понял... 2 раза перечитал

Comment: @StrangerintheQ , вы видите градиент во втором векторе? Он заполняется на весь круг, точно так же как и на первом, но мне нужно чтобы он заполнялся только в том объеме, в котором задам я. Если я задаю `stroke-dashoffset` для заполнения второго круга, то даже если я обрежу круг на половину, градиент будет работать на весь круг.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676477/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: svg не имеет такой опции ..можно умеличить stroke до огромных размеров ...

Comment: если к примеру circle разрезать на секции то он автоматом станет уже path ...

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/LYVmdWq я вот об этом говорю

Comment: @MaximLensky да, идея с `path` разумна. Я хотел сделать эффект заполненности круга и при этом чтобы эта часть имела линейный градиент именно той части, где она заполнена, но похоже что такое не получить через обычную разбивку, я не делал никогда такой эффект через `path`, поэтому не имею представления.

Comment: через path это будет геморой - надо js вкручивать

Comment: можно разбить круг по 90%  а на меньше я не умею ..может быть TT умеет