# Можно ли section задать стили?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Человек сказал, что секциям нельзя задавать стили, это правда? Можно где это написано в документации?

Добавлено: Он дополнил, что по бэм нельзя задавать стили, он имел в виду паддинги и маржины

Comment: Что такое «секция»? Вообще практически любому тегу можно задавать стили.

Comment: Секция - семантический элемент, который разделяет смысловые блоки и который имеет заголовок. В документации ничего особенного не нашёл

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section Этот что ли? Всё ему можно

Comment: По БЭМ-у можно задавать через модификаторы, какая разница модификатор блока или элемента, т.е. должно быть `<section class="block-name block-name_modifier"></section>` ну или ключ_значение в зависимости как вы БЭМ используете

Answer (score 0):

section это тоже элемент. Его можно стилизовать и управлять в js. Section это правильно будет добавить в article для удобно читаемости кода. Так что делай с ним что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

А вы попробуйте, проверить это практическим путём:

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section class = 'test'>123</section>
```

Comment: вопрос же был по БЭМ-у и по padding и margin

Comment: @Greg-- Хм. На момент моего ответа, вопрос звучал как "Можно ли section задать стили?". Из постановки вопроса, сложно понять, что это что-то про БЭМ.

Comment: Да, он потом добавил

Answer (score 0):

Вообще можно задавать, вот тут например посмотри второй комментарий [Как сверстать круг, разделенный на цвета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676477/)

По бэму, блок не должен иметь свои отступы и влиять на окружение, он должен работать сам по себе. Поэтому отступы на элементы прописывают.

Пример блока.
Например, каждая кнопка является блоком, она независма, её можно в любое место на сайте вставить и она будет работать.

Пример элемента.
Тег div, внутрь которого вложена кнопка, а мы её позиционируем в то или иное место на сайте.

Очень хорошо объясняет Виктория Ворожун. Посмотри на youtube, Виктория Ворожун Friday Live Coding

Comment: А если блоку модификтор задать с отступом?