# Индикация количества историй в border-radius как в телеграм премиум

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Скриншот из телеграм]подскажите пожалуйста как это делается?
В Телеграм премиум есть возможность выкладывать истории, там вокруг аватара пользователя создаётся border-radius 50%,и border 2px если есть история новая.
Но суть в том, что если историй много то border делится на равные части, к примеру 5 историй = 5 частям border с пробелом между ними.
Как это реализовать, или как это делается? Честно не могу найти информации нигде.

Comment: Хотя бы приложили скриншот)

Comment: SVG? Или другие варианты: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29006214/3129992), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61887478/3129992), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61887528/3129992).

Comment: Добивил скрин из телеграма, бордер поделен на 2 части равный 2 новым историям пользователя. Если было бы новых историй 5 было бы поделен на 5 частей бордер вокруг аватарки

Comment: В любом случае, я понимаю такое делается с использованием js не только html, css.

Comment: Если можете помогите с примером как это может выглядить, к примеру в скрипте подставлялось значение  <script>"количество историй 5"</script> и в html, css отображались изминения в border, то есть делился на равные части которые равны количеству историй.

Comment: Посмотрите и поиграйтесь с [этим примером](https://codepen.io/wmetz/pen/ONoRmV).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это не `border` и не `border-radius` точно, не знаю как это сделано в ТГ, но для сайтов я бы использовал SVG:

```js
// В функцию передаём параметры:
// num    (number)  - кол-во историй. Должно быть больше нуля.
// el     (node)    - элемент `.ava`
// isShow (boolean) - статус истории (просмотрен или нет). По дефолту false (не просмотрен)
function LenStories(num, el, isShow = false) {
    // Получаем в аватарке SVG circle
    const cir = el.querySelector('svg.ava__stories circle');
  // Если такого элемента нет, то прекращаем выполнение функции
  if(!cir) return false;
    
    // Если кол-во "историй" больше 1
    if(num > 1) { // 
        // Длина отступа
        const gap = 10;
        
        // Вычисляем длины пункта
        const totalLength = 2 * Math.PI * +cir.getAttribute('r');
        // Вычисляем отступ между пунктами
        const dashLength = (totalLength / num) - (gap * num) / num;

        // Выставляем значения
        cir.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', dashLength+' '+gap);
        cir.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', dashLength / 2);
    }
  
  // Если история просмотрена, то мы выставляем ей обводку другого цвета
  if(isShow) cir.setAttribute('stroke', '#404752');
}

// Это для демо
const ava = document.querySelectorAll('.ava');

LenStories(1, ava[0]);
LenStories(3, ava[1]);
LenStories(5, ava[2]);
LenStories(1, ava[3], true);
LenStories(10, ava[4], true);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #232b36;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.stories-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
}

.stories-container .ava:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.ava {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.ava__stories,
.ava__img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.ava__stories {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.ava__img {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  height: calc(100% - 16px);
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transform: translate(-100%, -100%); pointer-events: none;">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="ava-stories-fill" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
      <stop stop-color="#4fe965" offset="25%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#4fcddb" offset="75%"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>


<div class="stories-container">
  <div class="ava">
    <svg class="ava__stories" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="47" fill="none" stroke="url(#ava-stories-fill)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    </svg>
    <img class="ava__img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK61L.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="ava">
    <svg class="ava__stories" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="47" fill="none" stroke="url(#ava-stories-fill)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    </svg>
    <img class="ava__img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK61L.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="ava">
    <svg class="ava__stories" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="47" fill="none" stroke="url(#ava-stories-fill)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    </svg>
    <img class="ava__img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK61L.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="ava">
    <svg class="ava__stories" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="47" fill="none" stroke="url(#ava-stories-fill)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    </svg>
    <img class="ava__img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK61L.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="ava">
    <svg class="ava__stories" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="47" fill="none" stroke="url(#ava-stories-fill)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    </svg>
    <img class="ava__img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK61L.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Переделал на полноценный функционал, где есть вывод количества историй и сколько просмотренных:

```js
class AvaStories {
    cirCX = 50;
    cirCY = 50;
    cirR = 47;
    gap = 10;
    
    constructor(el, stories, viewed) {
        this.el = typeof el === 'string' ? document.querySelector(el) : el;
        if(!this.el && this.el.AvaStories) return false;
        
        this.svg = this.el.querySelector('.ava__stories');
        if(!this.svg) return false;
        
        this.draw(stories, viewed);
        
        this.el.avaStories = this;
    }
    
    draw(stories, viewed) {
        stories = this.storiesLen = stories > 0 ? stories : 0;
        viewed = this.viewedLen = viewed > 0 ? viewed : 0;
        
        const len = this.gap === 0 ? (360 / stories) : (360 - (this.gap * stories)) / stories;
        let prevStartAngle = 0;
        let prevEndAngle = 0;
        
        this.svg.innerHTML = '';
        
        if(stories === 1) {
            const seg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
            seg.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', this.cirCX);
            seg.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', this.cirCY);
            seg.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', this.cirR);
            seg.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', viewed === 0 ? 'url(#ava-stories-fill)' : '#404752');
            seg.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 3);
            this.svg.append(seg);
        } else {
            for(let i = 1; i <= stories; i++) {
                prevStartAngle = prevEndAngle + this.gap;
                prevEndAngle = (len * i) + (this.gap * i);
                
                const seg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
                
                seg.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', this.describeArc(this.cirCX, this.cirCY, this.cirR, prevStartAngle, prevEndAngle));
                seg.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'none');
                seg.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', viewed >= i ? '#404752' : 'url(#ava-stories-fill)');
                seg.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 3);
                
                this.svg.append(seg);
            }
        }
    }
    
    calcCoorInDeg(cx, cy, r, deg) {
        const a = (deg - 90) * Math.PI / 180;
        return {x: cx + (r * Math.cos(a)), y: cy + (r * Math.sin(a))}
    }
    
    describeArc(x, y, r, fromDeg, toDeg) {
        const startPos = this.calcCoorInDeg(x, y, r, toDeg);
        const endPos = this.calcCoorInDeg(x, y, r, fromDeg);
        const arcSweep = toDeg - fromDeg <= 180 ? 0 : 1;
        return [
            'M', startPos.x, startPos.y,
            'A', r, r, 0, arcSweep, 0, endPos.x, endPos.y
        ].join(' ');
    }
}

const ava = document.querySelectorAll('.ava');
[[1,0], [2, 1], [8, 0], [10, 3], [5, 5]].map((val, i) => new AvaStories(ava[i], ...val));


ava[2].addEventListener('click', () => {
  const avaStories = ava[2].avaStories;
  if(avaStories.viewedLen < avaStories.storiesLen) {
    avaStories.draw(avaStories.storiesLen, avaStories.viewedLen + 1);
    console.clear();
    console.log(avaStories.storiesLen, avaStories.viewedLen);
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #232b36;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.stories-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
}

.stories-container .ava:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.ava {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.ava__stories,
.ava__img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.ava__stories {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.ava__img {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transform: translate(-100%, -100%); pointer-events: none;">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="ava-stories-fill" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100" y2="100" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop stop-color="#4fe965" offset="25%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#4fcddb" offset="75%"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="stories-container">
  <div class="ava">
    <svg class="ava__stories" viewbox="0 0 100 100"></svg>
    <img class="ava__img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK61L.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="ava">
    <svg class="ava__stories" viewbox="0 0 100 100"></svg>
    <img class="ava__img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK61L.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="ava">
    <svg class="ava__stories" viewbox="0 0 100 100"></svg>
    <img class="ava__img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK61L.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="ava">
    <svg class="ava__stories" viewbox="0 0 100 100"></svg>
    <img class="ava__img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK61L.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="ava">
    <svg class="ava__stories" viewbox="0 0 100 100"></svg>
    <img class="ava__img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK61L.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если понажимать на третью аватарку, то вы увидите, как будет заполняться количество просмотренных историй.

Comment: Добрый день, это то что нужно!!! Огромное спасибо. Подскажите есть ещё один момент, если историй нет то есть 0,идет отображение ободка стандартного оттенка гардиента, а можно сделать когда историй 0 другой цвет?

Comment: Ещё обратил внимание, если заменить аватар с не равными размерами фото, то аватар становится яйцом в зависимости от размера изображения, при равных размерах аватара, этот баг отсутствует. Подскажите как его решить.

Comment: Изучайте основы вёрстки и этих вопросов будет меньше. Первое, у вас есть JS код, где вы изменяете отображение этой индикации, там дописываете дополнительные условия, чтобы ваша индикация была понятной. Второе, когда делают подобные элементы интерфейса, там всегда используют квадратные пропорции для изображений. Сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: P.s. когда историй 0, данный "пользователь" в историях вообще не должен появляться.

Comment: Если ответ правильный, и вам подошел, вы можете принять его в качестве верного, это можно сделать нажав галочку слева от ответа. @АндрейЧеремушкин

Comment: По поводу   P.S  Вы абсолютно правы. Но есть один момент, а может даже два, все истории просматриваются, после просмотра идёт обнуление индикации, что были просмотреные истории на ряду с другими непросмотреными историями других пользователей с индикацией. Но удаление просмотренного пользователя истории из списка доступных, не желательна, лучше обозначить как просмотреные, так как история имеет срок жизни. Да логично удалять просмотреные истории пользователя, как в инстаграм. Но решили пойти другим путем, может и не правильно.

Comment: Просто каждая история привязана к категории сайта и разделу, когда срок жизни истории выйдет автар и индикация будет удалена, а до удаления всегда доступна. Спасибо вам огромное, вы очень помогли, это именно то что искалось, все по полочкам разъяснили, ещё раз огромное спасибо.

Comment: Добрый вечер, спасибо за второй вариант, тоже очень интересное решение вопроса, но там есть какой-то баг, работает некоректно, удаляет истории и у другого пользователя при нажатии на 3 вариант, это происходит через раз, не сразу заметил это. Но решение очень достойное, немного сложнее конечно, там тоже есть вопрос, удаление истории в просмотреные после клика происходит осталось понять будет ли работать если истории смотрятся по порядку 1234, а не по отдельности, то есть по первому клику подряд несколько историй. Ну это наверно уже другая тема и вопрос тоже другой. Надо разбираться в коде сайта

Comment: Баг о котором я писал, скорее всего отображается здесь при выполнении кода, в редакторе не обнаружено.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как задействовать клик на всех без исключения и номера ava_stories?

Comment: @АндрейЧеремушкин, то, что используется у меня, это лишь демонстрация. Данный вопрос уже можно создавать как отдельный, но я бы советовал пойти другим путём. Во-первых, создание историй для сайта достаточно трудоёмкий процесс, в которым мы сейчас разобрались только с выводом кол-ва историй, но даже это не полноценный вариант, есть ещё куча нюансов и доработок. Я настоятельно рекомендую, если для вас это вызывает трудности и вы являетесь владельцем сайта для которого делаете - лучше обратитесь на фриланс, где опытные разработчики (фронд, бэк или фуллстек) сделают эту работу.

Comment: @АндрейЧеремушкин, либо отложите выполнение данного функционала, до момента пока не изучите   достаточно для выполнения данного функционала.

Comment: Добрый вечер, я немного отложил по времени как вы посоветовали, а подскажите пожалуйста в вашем примере не могу разобраться, как сделать кликабельные остальные, сейчас клик работает только на первом, я не силен в js, но от этой точки я смогу отталкнутся дальше, почти разобрался, но тут тупик может и маленький для вас, для меня огромный.

Answer (score 2):

Вот такое решение подойдёт, я думаю)

```js
var drSegment = function (style, ange1, ange2, id) {

  var dir = "0";
  if (angle2 - angle1 > 0.5 ) dir = "1";
  var angle1 = Math.PI * 2 * ange1;
  var angle2 = Math.PI * 2 * ange2;
  
  var rad=300, cx=350, cy=350;
  
  var dx1 = Math.sin(angle1) * rad + cx;
  var dy1 = -Math.cos(angle1) * rad + cy;
  
  var dx2 = Math.sin(angle2) * rad + cx;
  var dy2 = -Math.cos(angle2) * rad + cy; 
  
  var el= document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
  
  el.setAttribute('style', style);
  el.setAttribute('d', ' M '+dx1+','+dy1+' A '+rad+','+rad+' 0 ' + dir + ' 1 ' + dx2 + ',' + dy2 + ' L '+cx+','+cy+' Z');

  document.getElementById(id).appendChild(el);
  
}

function randomColor() {
    var color = '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(3, 9);
  return color
}
function createCircle(id, count) {
  for (let i = 1; i < count+1; i++) {
    drSegment(`fill:${randomColor()}; stroke:white; stroke-width:10;`, i/count, (i+1)/count, id)
  }
}

createCircle("s", 3)
```

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <img src="https://prophotos.ru/data/articles/0002/2614/image-rectangle_600_x.jpg" alt="">
        <svg id='s'viewBox="0 0 700 700"></svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: Добрый день, да это очень близко, но скорее всего реализуется через svg. В вашем варианте да это работает, но.. до определённого числа, потом идут баги и искожение. Отрисовка идёт надрывами, по этому я подумал здесь точно место быть svg.

Comment: Есть похожее, но как реализовать, честно не знаю и не силен в этом.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676516/218679

Comment: Так-то можно попробовать. Через час попробую

Comment: @АндрейЧеремушкин чекай, думаю, что подойдёт такое решение)
Просто внутри функции меняешь цифру и будет разное количество ободков

Comment: Хорошо спасибо, подожду

Comment: Да это супер, огромное спасибо! Но тут тоже есть момент при перезагрузке сперва видны разделённые части а потом загружается аватар, если бы можно было все таки имитировать border, было бы то что нужно, тут видны секции разделения. Так вообще можно сделать используя svg?

Comment: Ещё один момент, а можно использовать вместо random color секций градиент?

Comment: Есть баг, если ставить значение 1 тогда не создаётся ободок, работает только от значения 2

Comment: @АндрейЧеремушкин так цифра, это кол-во ободков => когда значение один, это будет целый ободок. Через border такое точно не сделать, а через svg я предоставил вариант. То, что аватарка грузится дольше, это уже от интернета зависит => можно подстелить под аву какой-то фон, чтобы не видеть секции полностью. Градиент можно использовать, глянь тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051351/svg-gradient-using-css